# I want to repeat a text in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to repeat a chunk of text in Vim.

I want to copy the following line:

```
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types`
```

and repeat it x number of times.

Example: 5 times

```
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types`
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types`
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types`
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types` 
truncate `Portal20`.`client_types`
```

I have done some research, but unable to locate a good resource.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do things efficiently in Vim: http://www.vimgolf.com/

Comment: If you happen to also have to write that line yourself, you could also use `5o[your line]<ESC>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the cursor to the line you want to copy, then press

```
yy
```

Then, press:

```
5p
```

Another nice technique (that also works for copying multiple lines) is to move the cursor to the line to copy, and select the line (in linewise-visual mode) by pressing

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

Press <kbd>y</kbd> to copy the line (or use the direction keys to move up or down to select more lines before copying).

Then press <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> as mentioned above to paste the copied block 5 times.

More documentation on visual mode is available in the documentation at: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html

Answer (score 4):

In [normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal) with your cursor anywhere on the line you wish to copy:

<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

[(Par 3)](http://www.vimgolf.com/)

**Explanation** (keys are hyperlinks to the online [`:help`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/helphelp.html#%3ahelp)):

- [<kbd>Y</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#Y) : Yank the line
- [<kbd>5</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#%5bcount%5d) : times
- [<kbd>p</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) : put the yanked text after the cursor

Comment: By default, `Y` yanks the whole line, not to the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> ? It copies the line your cursor is at, and paste it 5 times below it.